# Bios messing with Battery?

Tags: battery, bios, laptop

I'm sure that this isn't the most appropriate place to ask this question, but I know there are some really knowledgeable around here who probably can help me.

I've had an issue with a laptop not retaining a charge. At first I tried replacing the charger and then the battery and there is no change.

Symptoms, the battery seems to charge but extremely slowly, and so slow that the computer will not stay running long even when plugged in.

The computer won't turn on without the battery in but the charger in, but occasionally the power light will flicker.

If I leave the thing to charge the battery for a couple of hours it will start up fine and be normal for a while, but eventually dies again.

My question is could the Bios be causing this problem since my charger and battery are 3rd party? I don't understand why the charger seems to be steady connected when the battery is in, but completely disconnected when its not. This puzzles me.

I'm sorry that this isn't as strictly programming as it should be.

Comment: `I'm sure that this isn't the most appropriate place to ask this question, but I know there are some really knowledgeable around here who probably can help me.` ...

Comment: No, shouldn't be a BIOS issue.  But are you sure your charger is generating the correct output for your device?  No matter how slowly the battery charges, a laptop should _never_ stop running if it's plugged in.  It should also be able to power on with the charger attached and the battery removed.

Comment: I checked the charger and it's putting out the correct voltage.

Comment: Could it be some sort of motherboard issue? I just don't understand why it would charge some, but not how it is supposed to.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a third-party charger issue. What's the make and model of the laptop?

Comment: Well this sucks but I opened it up and there is a component on the mother board near the port that looks a little burnt. Its rectangular  and black about .5 X .3 cm. It appears to have one metal lead coming out of one end and 2 out of the other. Additionally, I've been trying to jiggle the cable around without the battery in and it acts like it wants to power on, but the power indicator just flickers on and off really fast.

Comment: @cody: That sounds like a power transistor or regulator. But if jiggling the connector helps, that tends to mean the connector has cracked off the board or isn't making good contact with the plug.

Comment: There was a problem on some older laptops of several brands that the charger connection would go bad like this.  Some repair shops know how to fix it.  The other possibility, as suggested above, is that you have the wrong charger (likely a few volts too low).  There's also a possibility, of course, that the battery is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your charging port on your laptop might be physically damaged.  This is very likely to be true if the charger connects loosely.

I then would suspect the charger as being defective before trying to replace the battery.

Agree with @aroth that it's probably not a BIOS issue.  Dell and HP BIOSes will put warning messages about incorrect or unknown battery/charger wattages but they will still boot.